# How to insert new line when generating xml from SQLPLUS

Tags: xml, oracle, sqlplus

The XML generated by using

```
XMLAgg(XMLElement('student', ...)...)
```

spits out everything onto one line. Given that I have a very large table, it reaches line length limit when spooling.

I'd like to have each <student>...</student> node on a separate line. [This](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/xmldatabase/entry/how_to_generate_xml_from_relational_data_with_line_breaks?lang=en) page suggests using XMLText(x'0A') to insert new lines, but SQLPlus doesn't seem to recognize it.

I've already tried :

```
set long 2000000000
set linesize 32767
set wrap on
set trimspool on
```

Comment: what oracle version as the xmlserialize with indent is only for 11g

Comment: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Prod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual trick in 10g was to add `.extract('/*')` on the outer xml operation you were doing eg

```
xmlagg(....).extract('/*')
```

but that doesn't work in 11g. for a cross version compatible one using an xsl transform see [Generate XML file with Customized XML tags out of oracle database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466485/generate-xml-file-with-customized-xml-tags-out-of-oracle-database-table/14469525#14469525).

10.2.0.4:

```
SQL> create table foo (id) as select rownum from dual connect by level <= 2;

Table created.

SQL> select xmlagg(xmlelement("id", xmlelement("id2", id))).extract('/*') a from foo;

A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<id>
  <id2>1</id2>
</id>
<id>
  <id2>2</id2>
</id>

SQL> select xmlserialize(content xmlagg(xmlelement("id", xmlelement("id2", id))).extract('/*') indent) a from foo;
select xmlserialize(content xmlagg(xmlelement("id", xmlelement("id2", id))).extract('/*') indent) a from foo
                                                                                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis


SQL> select xmlagg(xmlelement("id", xmlelement("id2", id))).transform(xmltype('<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  2   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  3   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  4   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  5    <xsl:copy>
  6     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  7    </xsl:copy>
  8   </xsl:template>
  9  </xsl:stylesheet>')) a from foo;

A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<id>
  <id2>1</id2>
</id>
<id>
  <id2>2</id2>
</id>
```

and 11.2.0.2/3:

```
SQL> select xmlagg(xmlelement("id", xmlelement("id2", id))).extract('/*') a from foo;

A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<id><id2>1</id2></id><id><id2>2</id2></id>

SQL> select xmlserialize(content xmlagg(xmlelement("id", xmlelement("id2", id))).extract('/*') indent) a from foo;

A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<id>
  <id2>1</id2>
</id>
<id>
  <id2>2</id2>
</id>

SQL> select xmlagg(xmlelement("id", xmlelement("id2", id))).transform(xmltype('<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  2   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  3   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  4   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  5    <xsl:copy>
  6     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  7    </xsl:copy>
  8   </xsl:template>
  9  </xsl:stylesheet>')) a from foo;

A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<id>
 <id2>1</id2>
</id>
<id>
 <id2>2</id2>
</id>
```

in short, to do this version agnositc, you should use a XSL. if you're only trying this for adhoc stuff, then `extract` is shorter to type on 10g and `xmlserialize`is shorter on 11g.

Comment: The adhoc solution for the 10g part works great, Thanks. I don't have an 11g environment, so can't verify that part.