# Oracle extract() stops XML output

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, sqlplus

I want to output to XML however I was having a problem because the single line XML output was being cut short even at the maximum size settings so I am now trying to use `extract()` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490661/how-to-insert-new-line-when-generating-xml-from-sqlplus) but the output starts and then stops at the same point each time.

There should be approximately 1000 orders being output.

SQL:

```
select
  xmlelement(
    "apiRequest",
    xmlelement(
      "orders",
      xmlagg(
        xmlelement(
          "order",
          xmlelement("order_no", order_no)
        )
      )
    )
  ).extract('/*') as xml
from
  orders
where
  order_date = '12-MAR-20';
```

Output:

```
XML
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<apiRequest>
  <orders>
    <order>
      <order_no>635359</order_no
```

This is where the output stops (there is no closing `>` and no further output after this).

Comment: What is your Oracle DB version?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky 10, that's why I am using `extract()` as per the linked question. The other XML functions to split the output are not present in 10.

Comment: are you doing this in sqlplus? xml comes out as a clob, so you need to SET LONG and SET LONCHUNKSIZE...also, Oracle 10 is ANCIENT, do whatever you can to upgrade that

Comment: I think it truncates the output because of settings on your SQLplus. Try `SET LONG` before you run the statement.