# How to output XML from a regular SQL query?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Oracle version 11g. I have a working SQL query in a PL/SQL procedure. What is the easiest way to take this query and output XML, either specifying the element names, or taking them from the query columns? I'm confused about whether to use DBMS_XMLGEN, XMLQuery or SQLX. What is the canonical way of doing this in Oracle?

Thanks

Comment: dbms_xmlgen should work.  Have you tried it?

Comment: check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466485/generate-xml-file-with-customized-xml-tags-out-of-oracle-database-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the SQL Functions generating XML http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb13gen.htm#i1029583. For example:

```
SELECT
   XMLRoot(
      XMLElement(
        "employees", 
        XMLAgg(
           XMLElement("employee",
              XMLConcat(
                 XMLElement(
                    "name",
                    e.name
                 ),
                 XMLElement(
                    "surname",
                    e.surname
                 )
              )
           )
        )
     ), VERSION '1.0', STANDALONE YES
  ).getClobVal() INTO retval -- useful if you want to export it outside oracle
  FROM employees e
```

should return for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<employees>
    <employee>
        <name>Jan</name>
        <surname>Kowalski</surname>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Tomasz</name>
        <surname>Nowak</surname>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Comment: **Thanks!** Better late than never.

Comment: useful answer, but kindly can I set alias for the result column instead of that strange long name ??? because when i set an alias  for it I got result in `(HUGECLOB)` but I need string result to be shown